# Nancy - Unable to resolve type: NHibernate.ISession

Tags: nhibernate, nancy

My `CustomBootstrapper` looks like below

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override NancyInternalConfiguration InternalConfiguration
    {
        get
        {
            //This will tell Nancy it won't have to look in the Nhibernate assemblies for implementations of our interfaces.
            return NancyInternalConfiguration
                .Default
                .WithIgnoredAssembly(asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("NHibernate", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                .WithIgnoredAssembly(asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("Fluent", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                .WithIgnoredAssembly(asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("Iesi", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }

    protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(TinyIoCContainer container, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.ConfigureRequestContainer(container, context);
        //container.Register((c, p) => SessionFactory.OpenSession());
        container.Register(SessionFactory.OpenSession());
    }
}
```

I have a repository which accepts `ISession` as a constructor dependency. When I run my application I get an error saying `Unable to resolve type: NHibernate.ISession`

I can confirm that

1. My bootstrapper is picked up by Nanacy
2. The `ISession` registration code is executed
3. I have tried commenting out `.WithIgnoredAssembly(asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("NHibernate", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))` from property `InternalConfiguration`
4. I get the error with both of the ways of registering component (one is commented in my code)

I have looked at similar other questions on SO and none has helped so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a sample project that uses NH with Nancy. In the bootstrapper I set up:

1. a BeforeRequest hook that creates the session and binds it to the session context
2. a AfterRequest hook that commits the session
3. an OnError hook that rolls back

The code is as follows:

```
public class Bootstrapper : WindsorNancyBootstrapper
{

 // other stuff

 protected override void ApplicationStartup(IWindsorContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
  {
    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);

    // other setup

    ConfigureNHibernateSessionPerRequest(container, pipelines);
  }

  private void ConfigureNHibernateSessionPerRequest(IWindsorContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
  {
    pipelines.BeforeRequest += ctx => CreateSession(container);
    pipelines.AfterRequest += ctx => CommitSession(container);
    pipelines.OnError += (ctx, ex) => RollbackSession(container);
  }

  private Response RollbackSession(IWindsorContainer container)
  {
    var sessionFactory = container.Resolve<ISessionFactory>();
    if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sessionFactory))
    {
      var requestSession = sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
      requestSession.Transaction.Rollback();
      CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(sessionFactory);
      requestSession.Dispose();
    }
    return null;
  }

  private Response CreateSession(IWindsorContainer container)
  {
    var sessionFactory = container.Resolve<ISessionFactory>();
    var requestSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(requestSession);
    requestSession.BeginTransaction();

    return null;
  }

  private AfterPipeline CommitSession(IWindsorContainer container)
  {
    var sessionFactory = container.Resolve<ISessionFactory>();
    if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sessionFactory))
    {
      var requestSession = sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
      requestSession.Transaction.Commit();
      CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(sessionFactory);
      requestSession.Dispose();
    }
    return null;
  }    
}
```

Comment: With this design, do you take a dependency on `ISessionFactory` wherever you need an `ISession`?

Comment: Yes. In e.g. repositories I take a constructor dependency on ISessionFactory.

Comment: That looks little odd to me. Repositories do not use `ISessionFactory` so they should not be taking dependency on `ISessionFactory`

Comment: Then register a factory method with your IoC container and have the factory pull the session from the ISessionFactory and inject that into the repositories.